# Spring classpath variable not working

Tags: java, xml, spring, applicationcontext

I'm trying to use `classpath` variable but I always get a `FileNotFoundException`.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
    xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop" xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc" xmlns:jpa="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.1.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.1.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.1.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.1.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa/spring-jpa.xsd">


    <tx:annotation-driven />
    <context:component-scan base-package="ar.com.conexia.salud.*" />

    <bean id="pdfGenerator" class="ar.com.conexia.generator.PdfGenerator">
<!--        <constructor-arg
            value="#{systemProperties['catalina.home']}/webapps/COMEI_Beneficiario/WEB-INF/classes/reports/" /> -->
        <constructor-arg value="classpath:/reports/" />
        <constructor-arg value="C://reports//" />
    </bean>

</beans>
```

As you can see, I tried using `catalina.home` variable as an alternative to check that I don't have any other problem with the file and it's fine.

Thanks.

**EDIT:** I concat those base paths with the file name in order to open files.

Answer (score 0):

try this
in the xml file put

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.your.package.name" />
```

and create class

```
@Configuration
public class Config {
    @Bean
    public PdfGenerator sessionFactoryBean(){
        PdfGenerator pdfGen=new PdfGenerator("classpath:/reports/","C://reports//");
        return pdfGen;
    }
}
```